# SQL report show result in one line of group

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to reach the follwoing result:

```
ID |  Part  | QTY| Boxes| Reference
1  | ABC123 | 20 | 0    | REF0001
2  | ABC345 | 10 | 0    | REF0001
3  | ABC487 | 5  | 1    | REF0001
4  | SEF453 | 4  | 0    | REF0002
5  | ABDS12 | 82 | 4    | REF0002
6  | EFR488 | 64 | 0    | REF0003
7  | XCV345 | 58 | 0    | REF0003
8  | SSFS33 | 23 | 3    | REF0003
```

Right now I get

```
ID |  Part  | QTY| Boxes| Reference
1  | ABC123 | 20 | 1    | REF0001
2  | ABC345 | 10 | 1    | REF0001
3  | ABC487 | 5  | 1    | REF0001
4  | SEF453 | 4  | 4    | REF0002
5  | ABDS12 | 82 | 4    | REF0002
6  | EFR488 | 64 | 3    | REF0003
7  | XCV345 | 58 | 3    | REF0003
8  | SSFS33 | 23 | 3    | REF0003
```

As you can see, the qty of boxes per reference repeat each row and i need to appear only one per reference.

Comment: Can you show your query?

Comment: ... And your base data, too?  And how do you determine the reference to show the quantity on?  (And why...)

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is one way . . .

```
with t as (<your current query>)
select ID, Part, QTY,
       max(Boxes) over (partition by Reference) as Boxes,
       Reference
from t
```

Answer (score 0):

Assigning row numbers grouped per each reference will mark highest ID sharing the same reference as 1; main query checks this mark and outputs zero if it is not satisfied.

```
; with q as
(
  select *,
         row_number() over (partition by Reference
                            order by ID desc) rn
    from
    (
        your-query-here
    ) a
)
select q.ID, 
       q.Part, 
       q.QTY, 
       case when rn = 1 then q.Boxes else 0 end as Boxes, 
       q.Reference
  from q
 order by q.ID
```